# Multiply hex number result in wrong sequence

Tags: perl, hex

I try to multiple one hex number by 10 and add to another hex number but the result i get is weird.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $address= 0x10000;
for ( $i =0 ; $i<=499 ; $i++ ) {
    my $line = hex($i+1)*10;
    my $new_address = $address + $line;
    print $new_address\n;
}
```

The answer i wan to get should be every 15 the `hex($i+1)` should become

```
hex(15) = F * 10 = F0
10000 + F0 = 100F0
hex(16) = 10 * 10 = 100
10000 + 100 = 10100
```

but my answer get is incorrect. Is my calculation wrong?

Comment: Your code won't compile and even if corrected shows a different output from what you have shown. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: How do you want it printed?  See `printf`

Comment: Better: `for my $i (0..499) { ... }`

Comment: Can i know why devote the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should convert to hexadecimal representation when printing values,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $address= 0x10000;
for (my $i =0 ; $i<=499 ; $i++ ) {
    # 10 != 0x10
    my $line = ($i+1)*0x10;
    my $new_address = $address + $line;
    # print sprintf("%X\n", $new_address);
    printf("%X\n", $new_address);
}
```

Comment: How about `printf` instead of `print sprintf`?

Comment: Of course; it might be just that OP want to store result somewhere.